# Variable performing like a pointer

Tags: java, android

In Java, I have two classes that each take values from a Singleton class but it seems to be changing values in the Singleton and I would just like a local copy.  This is a shortened version of whats happening in my classes.

method.getName() should return "Abbey", as thats how it was created earlier

```
public class MethodFragment1 extends Fragment {

    private Method method = MethodLab.get(getActivity()).getMethod();

    method.setName("Test");
}

public class MethodFragment2 extends Fragment {

    private Method method = MethodLab.get(getActivity()).getMethod();

    System.out.println(method.getName());
}
```

The output is "Test"

Do both classes not get a local copy of the `Method` from the `Singleton` class `MethodLab` and if not how do I get a local copy?

Comment: It is a Singleton so wouldn't that mean that MethodFragment1 and MethodFragment2 are both referencing the same object.

Comment: I suggest not using singletons. That is generally bad practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: Yeah, but they each get a local private copy......I thought

Comment: no, they get a pointer to the same object in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is singleton - it returns the same object for all callers. That's the whole point of singleton pattern - all callers get the same instance. If you want separate instance for each caller - just create new instance every time someone calls `getMethod()`:

```
Method getMethod()
{
     return new Method();
}
```

Basically, it is not clear what are you trying to do.. Alternatively you can return separate instance of "Something which provides method" every time someone calls `MethodLab.get()`. Hard to say w/o seeing your class structure

**EDIT**:
If you want to provide a copy of you object to callers, you can clone your `MethodProvider` (have no idea what your `MethodLab.get()` returns:) ). Please note, you need to push changes back when you done:

```
public class MethodLab
{
    private static MethodProvider provider = null;
    public static MethodProvider get()
    {
        //Not thread safe...
        if(provider == null)
        {
             provider = new MethodProvider();
             provider.getMethod().setName("Abby");
        }
        return provider.clone();
    } 

    public static set(MethodProvider newProvider)
    {
        provider = newProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it not return then a local object that I can manipulate without pushing all changes back to the Singleton class?

Comment: I really think you misunderstand Singleton pattern... With singleton all changes you make within local function, will be reflected on the main object. What you are operating with is just a pointer to the main object. Instance is only one

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you.  In that case, is there a way of getting a "local" copy?

Comment: You need to `clone` your object (either before or after) you call `getMethod`. In this case your method needs to implement `Clonnable` interface. You need to push your changes back to singleton though

Comment: Thanks man, solved it. Cloning did the trick, I misunderstood the Singleton concept